# TypeError: Cannot read proprty 'map' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using react to create a basic crud application for inventory management, however I am receiving this error on my DataTable.render

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined
```

The code it highlights is this

```
 27 | 
  28 |  render() {
  29 | 
> 30 |    const assets = this.props.assets.map(asset => {
     | ^  31 |      return (
  32 |        <tr key={asset.id}>
  33 |          <th scope="row">{asset.id}</th>
```

How would I go about fixing this?

Comment: your error means that `this.props.assets` is `undefined`, which suggests that you're not passing in `assets` as a prop to your component, or the value you're passing in is `undefined`

Comment: _How would I go about fixing this?_ - by making sure that `this.props.assets` is an array before calling `.map()` on it. This is probably because `this.props.assets` is `undefined` on an initial render. Make sure that `this.props.assets` is an empty array initially instead of `null` or `undefined`.

Comment: how are you passing the `assets` props to this component? as you can see the the `assets` is undefined

Comment: just add question mark `this.props?.assets.map`, but the right way to solve it is to add proptypes and default prop for `assets` prop...

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your `assets` prop is undefined. Doing something like this

```js
const assets = (this.props.assets || []).map(asset => {
```

should stop the error from happening. But it's really hard to say what the problem is without looking at the full component.

I'm guessing you're fetching the data using some sort of API, in that case, ideally you should have some sort of `loading` or `empty state`, and show that while the prop isn't ready yet.

Something like,

```
...
render() {
  if (this.props.assets === undefined) {
    return <Loading />
  }
  
  const assets = this.props.assets.map(asset => {
...
```

Answer (score 0):

It runbs into this error when `assets` array is received as emopty.
You can make use of **Nullish Coalescing Operator** which came out in ES2020. In your render, use

```
let assets = this.props.assets ?? [];
```

You can then use map function as per your logic

```
assets.map(() => {})
```

In this way if the `assets` is empty, it will automatically assign an empty array `assets` without breaking the code. Moreover, it reduces the amount of code to be written in order to cater this problem and makes the code look clean as well.